# apt security problem

Tags: apt

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/xerus-media/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntukylin-members/ukui/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntukylin-members/ukui3.0/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/vala-team/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: This is exactly answered by the linked duplicate - https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file - basically Jammy is still in development so MOST PPAs will not have release files for Jammy.  Also, **Jammy is offtopic** as it's currently in development.

Comment: i tried the solution there it isint working can u please help me

Comment: your only solution is to remove the PPA entries.  Jammy is still in development, and you can't 'fix' a PPA that doesn't have a release file for a release that has only been in development for 2 weeks so far.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *jammy* jellyfish [22.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu-next) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site [expected release date for Ubuntu 22.04 is 21 April 2022](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906)) when your question will be on-topic here.